# Typescript error : A 'super' call must be the first statement in the constructor when a class contains initialized properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, typescript

I have the following typescript errors in my project.. let me share
a sample so you can see what am dealing with.

```
module CoreWeb {
export class Controller implements IController {
    public $q;
    public $rootScope;
    public $scope:ng.IScope;
    public $state:ng.ui.IStateService;
    public $translate:ng.translate.ITranslateService;
    public appEvents;
    public commonValidationsService;
    public defaultPagingOptions = {
        currentPage: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
        totalServerItems: 0,
        maxSize: 5
    };
    public detailModelName:string;
    public filter:string;
    public listModelName:string;
    public mode;
    public modelDataService;
    public modelDefaultProperty:string;
    public ngDialog;
    public notificationsService;
    public pagingOptions:IPagingOptions;
    public selectionStatus:boolean;
    public serviceCreateFunction:string;
    public serviceGetAllCanceller:ng.IDeferred<any>;
    public serviceGetAllFunction:string;
    public serviceGetOneFunction:string;
    public serviceUpdateFunction:string;
    public showInactive:boolean;
    public tableAction:number;
    public tableActions:ITableAction[];
    public titleDataFactory;
    public validationOptions;
    public validationRules;
    public orderBy = null;
    public orderType = null;
    constructor(
        $q:ng.IQService,
        $rootScope,
        $scope:ng.IScope,
        $state,
        $translate:ng.translate.ITranslateService,
        appEvents,
        commonValidationsService,
        detailModelName:string,
        listModelName:string,
        modelDataService,
        modelDefaultProperty:string,
        ngDialog,
        notificationsService,
        serviceCreateFunction:string,
        serviceGetAllFunction:string,
        serviceGetOneFunction:string,
        serviceUpdateFunction:string,
        titleDataFactory
    ) {
        this.$q = $q;
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$state = $state;
        this.$translate = $translate;
        this.appEvents = appEvents;
        this.commonValidationsService = commonValidationsService;
        this.detailModelName = detailModelName;
        this.listModelName = listModelName;
        this.modelDataService = modelDataService;
        this.modelDefaultProperty = modelDefaultProperty;
        this.ngDialog = ngDialog;
        this.notificationsService = notificationsService;
        this.serviceCreateFunction = serviceCreateFunction;
        this.serviceGetAllCanceller = $q.defer();
        this.serviceGetAllFunction = serviceGetAllFunction;
        this.serviceGetOneFunction = serviceGetOneFunction;
        this.serviceUpdateFunction = serviceUpdateFunction;
        this.titleDataFactory = titleDataFactory;

        this.mode = $rootScope.modeEnum.none;
        this.pagingOptions = this.defaultPagingOptions;
        this.selectionStatus = false;
        this.showInactive = false;
        this.tableAction = null;
        this.tableActions = [
            {id: 1, name: "Activate"},
            {id: 2, name: "Deactivate"}
        ];
        this.validationOptions = {showErrors: commonValidationsService.modes.property, showNotification: true};

        this.activate();
    }
```

This is the class that extends the controller class.. one among many others

```
declare var App: ng.IModule;

module CoreWeb {
    export class EntityMasterController extends Controller {
        private currenciesDataSet;
        private entity: IEntityMasterModel;
        private merchandisingConstants;
        private typeAheadOptions;

    constructor(
        $q:ng.IQService,
        $rootScope,
        $scope:ng.IScope,
        $state,
        $translate:ng.translate.ITranslateService,
        appEvents,
        commonValidationsService,
        entityDataService,
        merchandisingConstants,
        ngDialog,
        notificationsService,
        titleDataFactory
    ) {
        this.merchandisingConstants = merchandisingConstants;
        super(
            $q,
            $rootScope,
            $scope,
            $state,
            $translate,
            appEvents,
            commonValidationsService,
            "entity",
            null,
            entityDataService,
            "name",
            ngDialog,
            notificationsService,
            "createEntity",
            "getCurrentEntity",
            "getEntity",
            "updateEntity",
            titleDataFactory
        );
    }
```

Now, if I initialize the `merchandisingConstants` before the super call like done above. I get the following error during gulp and my page does not display anything. A `super` call must be the first statement in the constructor when a class contains initialized properties or has parameter properties. I have tried all ways I can think of to fix these errors any idea of how I can go about this?

Comment: Well you could always stick that initialization in the `super` argument list via a comma operator or something.

Comment: What's the problem with moving the `this.merchandisingConstants` assignment below the `super` call?

Comment: I think it is very evident from the error message that you just need to move the `super(..` as the first statement in the constructor.

Comment: @pointy how can i do that?

Comment: Make the first parameter to `super()` be `(this.merchandisingConstants = merchandisingConstants, $q)` - that will have the effect of doing the assignment before the `super()` call happens, and it will also pass the value of `$q` just like in your code. Make sure you include the parentheses so that the `,` gets interpreted as the comma operator and not a comma separator in the parameter list.

Comment: @Kenney if i do it after the super, and try to access the merchandising constants, it throws undefined error

Comment: That's quite a hack by the way :)

Comment: @Pointy...u mean super(this.merchandisingConstants = merchandisingConstants, $q, $rootScope....

Comment: No - you need an **extra** set of parentheses around the part I posted in my previous comment - you want the value of the first argument to be `$q`, so you wrap your assignment and that in another layer of parentheses. I'll add an answer to be clearer.

Comment: You declare merchandisingConstants as a private field in the subclass; the base class doesn't and shouldn't have any knowledge of this: it extends the functionality of the base class, which is required to be set up first thing in the constructor. Having to use a hack bypassing the `call super() first` compiler check is indicative of a design flaw. If you move the assignment below the `super()` call, where is the EntityMasterController.merchandisingConstants accessed first, exactly?

Comment: its used first in the activate function where i initialize typeahead. the typeahead has to use some properties of the merchandisingConstants

Comment: This is not a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example. please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you extend a class, your constructor:

1. Must call `super()`
2. Must do that before it does anything else

In your instance, you just need to re-order things:

```
declare var App: ng.IModule;

module CoreWeb {
    export class EntityMasterController extends Controller {
        private currenciesDataSet;
        private entity: IEntityMasterModel;
        private merchandisingConstants;
        private typeAheadOptions;

    constructor(
        $q:ng.IQService,
        $rootScope,
        $scope:ng.IScope,
        $state,
        $translate:ng.translate.ITranslateService,
        appEvents,
        commonValidationsService,
        entityDataService,
        merchandisingConstants,
        ngDialog,
        notificationsService,
        titleDataFactory
    ) {
        // Must be first
        super(
            $q,
            $rootScope,
            $scope,
            $state,
            $translate,
            appEvents,
            commonValidationsService,
            "entity",
            null,
            entityDataService,
            "name",
            ngDialog,
            notificationsService,
            "createEntity",
            "getCurrentEntity",
            "getEntity",
            "updateEntity",
            titleDataFactory
        );

        this.merchandisingConstants = merchandisingConstants;
    }
```

Comment: this throws an error when i try to  use that controller. how can i initialize this before super?

Comment: Can you describe how the base class relies on this property?

Comment: the base class does not really relay on it, its a property that i need to use in my subclass

Comment: however if i initialize the property after the super call and try o use it in my code, i get a undefined error

Comment: Can you supply an example that shows the problem manifesting itself - `mechandisingConstants` must be used somewhere, perhaps the `super` constructor uses a method overridden in the sub class that depends on it?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a hack, but it is a simple workaround to the problem:

```
    super(
        (this.merchandisingConstants = merchandisingConstants, $q),
        $rootScope,
        $scope,
        $state,
        $translate,
        appEvents,
        commonValidationsService,
        "entity",
        null,
        entityDataService,
        "name",
        ngDialog,
        notificationsService,
        "createEntity",
        "getCurrentEntity",
        "getEntity",
        "updateEntity",
        titleDataFactory
    );
```

That uses the somewhat weird and not-often-useful JavaScript `,` operator to stuff the assignment in there as a side effect. You could do it with any of the parameters, really, but I did it with the first one. The comma operator — which is *not the same* as the comma that separates arguments to a function, even though of course it's exactly the same character — lets you string together a list of expressions, all of which will be evaluated. Only the last one is used as the value of the overall expression.

Thus, by doing that, you do your assignment while the argument list is being evaluated. The value of the first parameter will still be `$q`, but the assignment will happen too, before the function call to `super()` is made.

Comment: that works, gets rid of the super error.. however i get this error now.'this' cannot be referenced in current location.@pointy

Comment: @frontenddev ugh.  Well the underlying issue is that TypeScript wants the object to be initialized by the parent class before the subclass "touches" it. What this is really trying to tell you (not that I agree, necessarily) is that there's something impure about your object hierarchy: needing your subclass to initialize *before* the base class is the thing that the language doesn't like.